# Find $n$ where 15756 is the $n$th member of a set

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

It's a question from BNMO. It still haunts me a lot. I want to find an answer to this question.

> Any number of the different powers of $5: 1,5,25,125$ etc is added one at a time to 
>   generate the members of a set $S=\{1,5,6,25,26,30\dots\}$. If 15756 is the $n$th 
>   member of this ordered set, then find $n$.

Comment: Hint: what is $15756$ in binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers in $S$ are the positive integers of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{a_k}{5^k}\;,$$

where $m\ge 0$ and each $a_k$ is either $0$ or $1$. In other words, the base-five representation of each number consists entirely of zeros and ones. The first few are $1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000$; these are immediately recognizable as the numbers $1$ through $8$ in binary. A little thought shows that this is no accident. Can you finish it from here? If not, I’ve finished it in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse-over to see it.

> $15756=8192+4096+2048+1024+256+128+8+4=1111011000110_{\text{two}}$; reinterpreting this as $1111011000110_{\text{five}}$, we get $1,523,906,400$.